# POST json in C# return number

Tags: c#, json

I have a problem with the POST method. I have a REST server programmed in C#, and I want to consume this REST service in C#, but I don't know how. The problem is that my method accepts a POST, receives a JSON payload and returns an `HTTPStatusCode` and a number:

```
id_task= planificadorService.CreaTarea(tareaDTO);//tareaDTO is a JSON

if (id_tarea == 0)
{
    response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Cannot create task ");
    return response;
}

response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
response.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id_task), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
return response;
```

It was easy to do it using the GET method with the `WebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse` classes, but I don't know how to do it with the POST method. After many attempts, I ended up with something like this:

```
public void PostTareas(Tarea tarea)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_base + "/v1/tareas");
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tarea);

    var client = new HttpClient()
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(url_base + "/v1/tareas")
    };

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    HttpResponseMessage response;

    response.Content= new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tarea).ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    response = client.PostAsync(url_base + "/v1/tareas", json)).Result;
}
```

I'm on the right track? How can I do this so that I am able to access the Json content? Thanks

P.D- Excuse my english, it is not my native language and I know there may be faults in expressing myself

Comment: What status code is it returning, any errors whilst debugging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `WebRequest` you need to write the JSON in the POST request payload, use [`WebRequest.GetRequestStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getrequeststream(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url_base + "/v1/tareas");
...
using(var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
  // Write the serialized json into the stream, it will be send as payload
  using(TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream)) {
    writer.WriteLine(JsonConvert.Serialize(tarea));
  }
}
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

*or* you can use `HttpClient` and call `PostAsync`, as you're doing in your second part of your code. Either way is fine, but stick to one :)

You should also consider using a high(er) level library, like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/). Ultimately consider exposing your server API with Swagger via [Swashbuckle](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle), generate a client with [swagger-codegen](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen) and spend your time at the higher level abstraction of the API, not the HTTP/Json layer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
After running it install a library called Flurl as you told me, and all right!